# WSDLToJava: NPE in AbstractGenerator calling new VelocityGenerator(false) when org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger is on the classpath

Tags: wsdl, cxf, classpath, velocity

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in `Hashtable` when calling `WSDLToJava` after upgrading to CXF 3.4.1.

Full stack trace:

```
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Tools can not load the frontend plugin class org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AntGenerator
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndGenerators(PluginLoader.java:275)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndProfile(PluginLoader.java:385)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.loadFrontEnd(WSDLToJava.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Failed to initialize velocity engine
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.VelocityGenerator.initVelocity(VelocityGenerator.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.VelocityGenerator.<init>(VelocityGenerator.java:53)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.AbstractGenerator.<init>(AbstractGenerator.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AbstractJAXWSGenerator.<init>(AbstractJAXWSGenerator.java:30)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AntGenerator.<init>(AntGenerator.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndGenerators(PluginLoader.java:270)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.addPropertyInternal(ExtendedProperties.java:723)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.addProperty(ExtendedProperties.java:671)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.setProperty(ExtendedProperties.java:737)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.convertProperties(ExtendedProperties.java:1693)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:645)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:226)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.VelocityGenerator.initVelocity(VelocityGenerator.java:87)
    ... 34 more
```

What's wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractGenerator` calls `VelocityGenerator(false)` which sets the field `log` to `false`.

The code in `initVelocity()` will then create an instance of `org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger` (if it can) and put that into the `Properties` instance.

Eventually, `org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.convertProperties(Properties)` will be called. This line

```
c.setProperty(s, props.getProperty(s));
```

results in call to `Hashtable.put(s, null)` because `Properties.getProperty()` will return `null` for non-String elements in the map like the `NOPLogger` instance.

The culprit is that you have two implementations of Velocity on the classpath. One has version 1.x with the coordinate `org.apache.velocity:velocity` and one `org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core` with version 2.2.

Exclude the dependency to Velocity 1.x to fix this error. Velocity 2.x uses `ExtProperties` instead of `ExtendedProperties` which contains a patch for this bug.